# iOS: Changing UIButton Title through Delegate

Tags: ios, uibutton, delegation

I'm using delegation to change the title of a UIButton.

.h MainView

```
//MainViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SignUpDelegate;
@protocol SignUpDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)loggedIn;
@end

@interface MainViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
{
     id <SignUpDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SignUpDelegate> delegate;
-(void)loggedIn;

@end
```

.m

```
@interface MainViewController ()
//This button is connected to the UINavigationBar Button that needs its title changed.
//Via Interface Builder, the default value of the title is setup as "Login"
-@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *logInOutButton;
@end    

-(void)loggedIn
{
    NSLog (@"This is Logged in inside MainView.m");
    self.logInOutButton.title = @"Logout";
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    Signup *signUp = [destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[Signup class]] ? (Signup*)destinationViewController : nil;
    signUp.mainViewController = self.delegate;
}
```

.h SignUp

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"
@interface SignUp : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, SignUpDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) MainViewController *mainViewController;
@end
```

.m

```
@synthesize mainViewController;
- (IBAction)createUser:(id)sender
{
   [self loggedIn];
}

- (void) loggedIn
{
    NSLog (@"This is Logged in inside SignUp");
    [mainViewController loggedIn];
}
```

So, both NSLogs Print fine, which I think means the delegate is working, however, the title on the UIButton on the Navigation Bar never changes to "Logout"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you recreate `STMasterViewController` (should this have been `MainViewController` instead?) every time in the `loggedIn` delegate method. (You can verify this by adding a breakpoint on `-[MainViewController loggedIn]` and checking if `self.logInOutButton` is non-nil). Instead you should get the reference to existing instance of `MainViewController` and operate on that.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, it's suppose to be MainViewController (sorry, I'm paranoid and change the actual variable names).  How do I get a reference to the existing instance of MainViewController?

Comment: @user1107173 How is `SignUpController` created?

Comment: It's a segue created in Storyboard.

Comment: @user1107173 In the `prepareForSegue:sender:`, after creating `SignUpController` instance, set it's delegate.

Comment: What do you mean set it's delegate? Can you please provide an example?  Thanks

Comment: Show me the code for `prepareForSegue:sender:` when you create sign up controller.

Comment: I don't have that method b/c I created a Segue with Storyboard.

Comment: @user1107173 Add `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{ if (segue.identifier isEqual: @"YOUR_SEGUE_ID"){ SignUp *signUpVc = segue.destinationViewController; signUpVc.delegate = self;  } }` in `MainViewController`. This (optional) method is called when a segue transition is about to happen.

Comment: SignUp does not have a .delegate property.

Comment: Other way around then! `self.delegate = signUpVc;`

Comment: I think I can only use segue.identifier when going forward.  What do I use when popping from the navigation stack?

Comment: So, I tired your strategy and didn't work :(  I think I did it how you suggested it.  I updated the code.  Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29340/discussion-between-mar0ux-and-user1107173)